# SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server

HI

Does anyone know of an application which will backup MSSQL DBs to .Bak backups from a remote location?

Comment: You should look back on your questions and consider marking them as "answered" if you expect people to continue answering.

Comment: Sure: SQL Server Management Studio! :) Or is there some functionality you're looking for that it's lacking?

Comment: Management studio or any Enterprise level backup application. What is it you are looking for in particular, what sort of options, price range etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be any backup solution.  The native tools can do this, as can just about any backup product.  You'll need the SQL Server plug in from the backup company so that the software knows that it is logging into a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

you could try telnet and running sqlcmd utility or writing a bat file to perform the .bak creation, or you could schedule a task to run it for you or you could use MS backup tools or you could use MS SQl Management studio.

Bit vague on the question?